# How to replace a word in dataframe by using another dataframe in Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

`df`:

```
id   string_data
1    My name is Jeff
2    Hello, I am John
3    I like Brad he is cool.
```

Another data frame named `allnames` contains a list of names like this:

```
id  name
1   Jeff
2   Brad
3   John
4   Emily
5   Ross
```

I want to replace all the words in `df` that appear in `allnames['name']` with `"Firstname"`

Expected output:

```
id   string_data
1    My name is Firstname
2    Hello, I am Firstname
3    I like Firstname he is cool.
```

I tried this:

```
nameList = '|'.join(allnames['name'])
df['string_data'].str.replace(nameList, "FirstName", case = False))
```

But it replaces almost 99% of the words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution should working if add words boundaries to [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
nameList = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in allnames['name'])
df['string_data'] = df['string_data'].str.replace(nameList, "FirstName", case = False)
print (df)
   id                   string_data
0   1          My name is FirstName
1   2         Hello, I am FirstName
2   3  I like FirstName he is cool.
```

Or replace values with `get` and `join` by dictionary:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(allnames['name'], 'Firstname')
f = lambda x: ' '.join(d.get(y, y) for y in x.split())
df['string_data'] = df['string_data'].apply(f)
print (df)
   id                   string_data
0   1          My name is Firstname
1   2         Hello, I am Firstname
2   3  I like Firstname he is cool.
```

EDIT: You can convert all values to lowercase by `lower`:

```
d = dict.fromkeys([x.lower() for x in allnames['name']], 'Firstname')
f = lambda x: ' '.join(d.get(y.lower(), y) for y in x.split())
df['string_data'] = df['string_data'].apply(f)
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your first solution. It replace the word `That's` with `Firstnamehat's`. Other words are just fine, i will check second and third solution now.

Comment: @JohnDoe - First solution should failed, so removed.

Comment: It happened because I had a name named `T`, but it still failed. Thanks a lot. Second solution works perfectly

Comment: Hey, the first solution is case insensitive and very slow. Second solution is case sensetive and fast. Is there case insensitive and fast solution?

Comment: @jezrael if I put the df1 and allnames data frame in 2 excel sheets how I need to join them get the result set